# java.net BalloonTip is not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip, listselectionlistener

I saw the [BallonTip](http://balloontip.java.net/) at java.net and I tried to integrate it into my application to be displayed when a user clicks a table cell. When a table cell is clicked, the BalloonTip is showing up as intended, but when you scroll it out of the current viewport, you can click another cell without the BalloonTip showing up. When you scroll the table, the BallonTip is shown again.

Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import net.java.balloontip.BalloonTip;
import net.java.balloontip.TablecellBalloonTip;
import net.java.balloontip.styles.EdgedBalloonStyle;

public class TableTest2 extends JFrame {

static final int LENGTH = 40;
TablecellBalloonTip tip;
JTable mainTable;
JPanel main;
JLayeredPane layeredPane;
JScrollPane mainScroll;

TableTest2() {
    mainTable = new JTable(LENGTH, LENGTH);
    CustomListSelectionListener clsl = new CustomListSelectionListener(mainTable);
    mainTable.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(clsl);
    mainTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(clsl);
    mainTable.setTableHeader(null);
    mainTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    mainScroll = new JScrollPane(mainTable);
    add(mainScroll);

    tip = new TablecellBalloonTip(mainTable, new JLabel("Hello World!"), -1, -1, new EdgedBalloonStyle(Color.WHITE,
            Color.BLUE), BalloonTip.Orientation.LEFT_ABOVE, BalloonTip.AttachLocation.ALIGNED, 5, 5, false);

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TableTest2();
}

protected class CustomListSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {
    private int row, column, lead, anchor;
    private JTable table;

    public CustomListSelectionListener(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() == table.getSelectionModel() && table.getRowSelectionAllowed()) {
            // row selection changed
            row = table.getSelectedRow();
            column = table.getSelectedColumn();
            tip.setCellPosition(row, column);
            tip.refreshLocation();
        } else if (evt.getSource() == table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel()
                && table.getColumnSelectionAllowed()) {
            // column selection changed
            lead = table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
            anchor = table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().getAnchorSelectionIndex();
            if (lead <= anchor) {
                column = anchor;
            } else {
                column = lead;
            }
            row = table.getSelectedRow();
            tip.setCellPosition(row, column);
            tip.refreshLocation();
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can I force the BalloonTip to be shown after I click a cell in the table? I think there is a listener, which is listening for the scrolling event and manages the painting of the BallonTip, but I do not have a clue which one it is.

best regards
htz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [to this mailing list](http://java.net/projects/balloontip/lists/users/archive/2012-10/message/0), there was a bug in the BallonTip version 1.2.1. Now, with version 1.2.3, this is fixed.

Comment: Is there an official place where latest version could be downloaded?
Link in the mailing list points to the dropbox... Not to the project page.

Comment: On the [project page](https://java.net/projects/balloontip) there is only the 1.2.1 version. The Dropbox link seems to be the only source for the 1.2.3 version yet.

Comment: I found this link posted in mailing list by component author. So it looks like we can consider it as a trusted source =)